# Compare two arrays and count number of the same strings

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to compare two arrays in two columns and in the third column return the number of the same strings within those two arrays.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      column 1       |     column 2     |     column 3     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   [cat, dog, bird]  |   [cat, bird]    |          2       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  [cat, bear, tiger] |      [tiger]     |          1       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    [cat, tiger]     |  [tiger, cat]    |          2       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: it is good practice here on SO to vote up for answers which helped and if accept the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unnest()`.  Assuming that the individual arrays have no duplicates:

```
with t as (
      select array['cat', 'dog', 'bird'] as column1, array['cat', 'bird'] as column2 union all
      select array['cat', 'bear', 'tiger'], array['tiger'] union all
      select array['cat', 'tiger'], array['tiger', 'cat']
     )
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from unnest(column1) el1 join
             unnest(column2) el2
             on el1 = el2
       ) as column3
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no duplicates withing the arrays - below is another option

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(
    SELECT item
    FROM UNNEST(column1 || column2) AS item
    GROUP BY item
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  )) AS column3
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

What above query does - it combines two arrays, than removes all non-duplicates while leaving distinct list of duplicates and finally counts number of elements in resulted array

Yet another, I think most simplest/straightforward approach is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM t.column1 INTERSECT DISTINCT 
    SELECT * FROM t.column2
  )) AS column3
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

I do't think last version requires any explanation

Obviously both above versions return expected output as

```
Row column1             column2         column3  
1   [cat, dog, bird]    [cat, bird]     2    
2   [cat, bear, tiger]  [tiger]         1    
3   [cat, tiger]        [tiger, cat]    2
```