# how to find difference between following rows in an array in SQL snowflake?

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to compare two arrays of the following rows(group by) in the same column and return the array and total number in different columns. I want to have similar results mentioned on this link [Compare two arrays and count number of the same strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934093/compare-two-arrays-and-count-number-of-the-same-strings). But over here arrays are compared between columns but I would like to compare between rows.

So, my initial dataset might look like this

```
|Id.       |      column 1       | 
|----------|---------------------|
|1         |   [cat, dog, bird]  |
|1         |.  [cat, bird]       |
|1         |   [cat, bear, tiger]| 
|1         |.  [cat, tiger]      |
|2         |   [cat, tiger]      |
|2         |   [cat, bear, tiger]|  
|2         |   [cat, bird]       |
|3         |.  [tiger]           |
|3         |.  [cat, bird]       |
```

So, my final dataset might look something like this.

```
|Id.       |      column 1       |     column 2     |     column 3     |
|----------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|1         |  [cat, dog, bird]   |  [dog]           |          1       |
|1         |. [cat, bird]        |  [bird]          |          1       |
|1         |  [cat, bear, tiger] |  [bear]          |          1       |
|1         |  [cat, tiger]       |. [cat, tiger ]   |                  |
|2         |  [cat, tiger]       |                  |          0       |
|2         |  [cat, bear, tiger] |  [bear, tiger].  |          2       |    
|2         |  [cat, bird]        |  [cat, bird]     |                  |
|3         |  [tiger]            |  [tiger]         |          1       |
|3         |  [cat, bird]        |  [cat, bird      |                  |
```

column 2 contains information about the first array but does not belong to the second array and column 3 contains information about how many elements are inside column 2.

Thank You

Comment: You can use ```lead``` function to compare to next row.

Comment: Would you mind providing the new prototype of `lead`. I went through `lead` but I was not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

So the LEAD example:

```
with data(id, _order, col1) as (
    select column1, column2, parse_json(column3)
    from values
        (1, 1, '["cat", "dog", "bird"]'),
        (1, 2, '["cat", "bird"]'),
        (1, 3, '["cat", "bear", "tiger"]'),
        (1, 4, '["cat", "tiger"]'),
        (2, 5, '["cat", "tiger"]'),
        (2, 6, '["cat", "bear", "tiger"]'),
        (2, 7, '["cat", "bird"]'),
        (3, 8, '["tiger"]'),
        (3, 9, '["cat", "bird"]')
)
select *
    ,lead(col1) over (partition by id order by _order ) as lead_col1
from data
order by _order;
```

| ID | _ORDER | COL1 | LEAD_COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | [ "cat", "dog", "bird" ] | [ "cat", "bird" ] |
| 1 | 2 | [ "cat", "bird" ] | [ "cat", "bear", "tiger" ] |
| 1 | 3 | [ "cat", "bear", "tiger" ] | [ "cat", "tiger" ] |
| 1 | 4 | [ "cat", "tiger" ] | null |
| 2 | 5 | [ "cat", "tiger" ] | [ "cat", "bear", "tiger" ] |
| 2 | 6 | [ "cat", "bear", "tiger" ] | [ "cat", "bird" ] |
| 2 | 7 | [ "cat", "bird" ] |  |
| 3 | 8 | [ "tiger" ] | [ "cat", "bird" ] |
| 3 | 9 | [ "cat", "bird" ] | null |

Anyways: here's the code how I would do it:

```
with data(id, col1) as (
    select column1, parse_json(column2)
    from values
        (1, '["cat", "dog", "bird"]'),
        (1, '["cat", "bird"]'),
        (1, '["cat", "bear", "tiger"]'),
        (1, '["cat", "tiger"]'),
        (2, '["cat", "tiger"]'),
        (2, '["cat", "bear", "tiger"]'),
        (2, '["cat", "bird"]'),
        (3, '["tiger"]'),
        (3, '["cat", "bird"]')
), flatten as (
    select
        d.id, 
        dense_rank() over(order by f.seq) as seq, 
        f.index, 
        f.value as val
    from data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.col1)) f
)
select 
    a.id
    ,a.seq
    ,array_agg(a.val) within group (order by a.index) as col1
    ,array_agg(nvl2(a.val, nvl2(b.val, null, a.val), b.val)) within group (order by a.index) as col2
    ,array_size(col2 )as col3
from flatten as a
full outer join flatten as b 
    on a.id = b.id and a.seq + 1 = b.seq and a.val = b.val
where a.id is not null
group by a.id, a.seq
order by a.seq;
```

| ID | SEQ | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | [ "cat", "dog", "bird" ] | [ "dog" ] | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | [ "cat", "bird" ] | [ "bird" ] | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | [ "cat", "bear", "tiger" ] | [ "bear" ] | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | [ "cat", "tiger" ] | [ "cat", "tiger" ] | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | [ "cat", "tiger" ] | [] | 0 |
| 2 | 6 | [ "cat", "bear", "tiger" ] | [ "bear", "tiger" ] | 2 |
| 2 | 7 | [ "cat", "bird" ] | [ "cat", "bird" ] | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | [ "tiger" ] | [ "tiger" ] | 1 |
| 3 | 9 | [ "cat", "bird" ] | [ "cat", "bird" ] | 2 |

Comment: Hi Simeon, Thank you for your answer but your answer does not much with my expected result. Would you mind reviewing my expected result table?

Comment: Oh I got that, but you did point out you don't know how to use LEAD, so I just showed that..

Comment: How do we print the opposite results as you have done? For example, you have printed `[ "cat", "bird" ]` in the first row instead of that I want to print `['dog']`. How can I do that?

Comment: unfortunately snowflake does not have a array_subtract function (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-semistructured.html) so really this just needs to be solved the way Gordon shows, OR via a Javascript function, and doing the SET logic is JS

Comment: Given the output I have provided, is the input to Gordans solution, you should be able to step to a working solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247576/discussion-between-bad-coder-and-simeon-pilgrim).