# Match two sets of columns that contain same elements regardless of order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named `purchases` and `dimensions`, both contains these three separate columns `height`, `length`, `width`. In the `dimensions` table there are about 120 **unique combinations** of dimensions as shown below. (regardless of the order, so for example `10,10,12` won't exist if there is already `10,12,10`).

In `purchases` the dimensions are stored but could be in a different order. (For example it's stored `10,10,12` in `dimensions` but could be stored as `10,12,10` or `12,10,10` in `purchases`.)

[All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements) [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934093/compare-two-arrays-and-count-number-of-the-same-strings) I found ignores duplicates, but since `10,10,12` should be consider different from `10,12,12`, I can't figure out how to adapt those solutions.

Is there a way to use SQL to update each purchase's `dimension_id`? (Must leave it `NULL` if not exist dimension combination.)

```
dimensions

    id    height    width    length
    1     10        10       12
    2     10        12       12


purchases

    order_number    height    width    length    dimension_id
    1               10        12       10        NULL  <- to 1
    2               10        12       12        NULL  <- to 2
    3               10        12       15        NULL  <- still NULL
```

---

**Edit:**
Renamed `orders` to `purchases` to avoid ambiguousness between table name and the "order" of data.

The version I'm using is `Microsoft SQL Server 2017`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: UPDATE orders 
INNER JOIN dimensions ON 
dimensions.height=orders.height
AND dimensions.width=orders.width
AND dimensions.length=orders.Length
SET orders.dimension_id = dimensions.id

Comment: @bart-mcendree the orders of the dimensions could be different (not necessary), this only works when the orders of the dimensions are the same.

Comment: @yitzhak-khabinsky Thanks for your reply, though I believe this is a **how-to** question that doesn't require a minimal-reproducible-example since it will only add noises to the question. Please refer to [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427513/9107694).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have only three dimensiomns you don't need a fancy pivot or something else

This query would immensely profit from an index on height, width and length.

```
UPDATE o
  SET o.dimension_id = dimensions.id
  FROM purchases o INNER JOIN dimensions ON 
  (dimensions.height=o.height AND dimensions.width=o.width AND dimensions.length=o.Length)
  OR
  (dimensions.height=o.width AND dimensions.width=o.Length AND dimensions.length=o.height)
  OR
  (dimensions.height=o.Length AND dimensions.width=o.height AND dimensions.length=o.width)
  Or 
  (dimensions.height=o.Length AND dimensions.width=o.width AND dimensions.length=o.height)
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM purchases
```

| order_number | height | width | length | dimension_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 12 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 12 | 12 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | 12 | 15 | *null* |
| 4 | 12 | 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 4 | 10 | 10 | 12 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NZGrQ8_a)

Answer (score 1):

Every permutation of valid matches can be specified in the join

```
UPDATE  o
SET o.dimension_id = d.id  
FROM orders o INNER JOIN dimensions d ON 
      --all match  
(d.height=o.height AND d.width=o.width AND d.length=o.Length)
OR    --swap width and length  
(d.height=o.height AND d.width=o.Length AND d.length=o.Width)
OR    --swap length and height  
(d.height=o.Length AND d.width=o.width AND d.length=o.Height)
OR    --swap all  
(d.height=o.Length AND d.width=o.Height AND d.length=o.Width)
```

[fiddler](https://dbfiddle.uk/MEPtwOnY)

Comment: Apologize for the table rename in my question post. You don't need to rename the table name in your answer.

Comment: that query will not run you can test it in  my fiddle

Comment: Oh you're right, I just typed out all combinations myself when I tried so I didn't notice the incorrect syntax, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Corrected syntax. added fiddler link.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize your dimensions on both sides and then do a join:

```
SELECT  *
INTO dimensions 
FROM
(
    VALUES  (1, 10, 10, 12)
    ,   (2, 10, 12, 12)
) t (id,height,width,length)

SELECT  *, NULL AS dimId
INTO orders 
FROM
(
    VALUES  (1, 9, 12, 10)
    ,   (2, 10, 12, 12)
    ,   (3, 10, 12, 15)
    ,   (4, 7, 13, 12)
    ,   (5, 10, 12, 10)
    ,   (6, 10, 5, 3)
) t (order_number,height,width,length)

UPDATE  o
SET dimId = dim.id
FROM    orders o
cross apply (
    select  STRING_AGG(val, ',') WITHIN GROUP(order by val) AS dims
    from(
        values(height), (length), (width)
        ) x (val)
    ) ax
cross apply (
    select  STRING_AGG(val, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY val) AS dims
    ,   dim.id
    from    dimensions dim
    cross apply (
        values(height), (length), (width)
        ) x (val)
    group by dim.id
    ) dim
where   dim.dims = ax.dims
```

This creates "ordered" dimension values like `10,10,12` and joins on them between the two tables. If your dimension table is already normalized you can save some typing